# 5 if statement formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I recently created an IF formula to run inside a macro for only 2 statements but I need to add 3 more to it.

This is for altering a filename. So I use the `LEN` to determine what type of file it is then run the appropriate formula to trim out what I don't want.

**Examples:**

173d0221.pdf = S-173-D022 Description.pdf
 `=CHAR(83)&CHAR(45)&LEFT(B11,LEN(B11)-9)&CHAR(45)&UPPER(MID(B11,4,LEN(B11)-8))&CHAR(32)&D11&E11`

173d02210.pdf = S-173-D022 Description.pdf `=CHAR(83)&CHAR(45)&LEFT(B12,LEN(B12)-10)&CHAR(45)&UPPER(MID(B12,4,LEN(B12)-9))&CHAR(32)&D12&E12`

173d170c141.pdf = SD-170-C14 Description.pdf 
 `=CHAR(83)&CHAR(68)&CHAR(45)&UPPER(MID(B13,5,LEN(B13)-12))&CHAR(45)&UPPER(MID(B13,8,LEN(B13)-12)&CHAR(32)&D13&E13)`

REF-173d0221.pdf = REF-173-D022 Description.pdf 
 `=LEFT(B14,LEN(B14)-9)&CHAR(45)&UPPER(MID(B14,8,LEN(B14)-12))&CHAR(32)&D14&E14`

REF-173d02210.pdf = REF-173-D022 Description.pdf 
 `=LEFT(B15,LEN(B15)-10)&CHAR(45)&UPPER(MID(B15,8,LEN(B15)-13))&CHAR(32)&D15&E15`

I am having trouble linking them together to get it to apply the right formula based on the length of the cell.

*Notes:* I am using `CHAR(83)&CHAR(45)` instead of `"S-"` because VBA wasn't liking the text. I will update the `"B12"` cell tag with `" & aCell & "` once everything is working smoothly.

*My vba code looks like:*

```
.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(LEN(" & aCell & ")=12,CHAR(83)&CHAR(45)&LEFT(" & aCell & ",LEN(" & aCell & ")-9)&CHAR(45)&UPPER(MID(" & aCell & ",4,LEN(" & aCell & ")-8))&CHAR(32)&" & dCell & "&" & eCell & ",LEFT(" & aCell & ",LEN(" & aCell & ")-9)&CHAR(45)&UPPER(MID(" & aCell & ",8,LEN(" & aCell & ")-12))&CHAR(32)&" & dCell & "&" & eCell & ")"
```

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the output as a *formula*, i.e., do you need it to be dynamic in case the values in column B change, or is it sufficient to just re-work the macro to handle these lengths and output a string literal value in each cell in column C?

Comment: I use `" & aCell & "` in my macro so when the formula is applied it adds in the correct cell. ie., `"A2"` I am just trying to add all of them together and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking whether the *output* from the macro needs to be retained as a *formula* in the output cells, or whether it would be OK to simply output the *values*.

Comment: oh, values would be better actually. It would be nice to do a `If` and `ElseIf` in my macro to handle this.

Comment: much easier to implement that. hold on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for the first three example formula.

[image]

I'll leave it to you to translate the remaining 2 formula to VBA, which you should be able to do following my examples :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim val As String
Set rng = Range("B1:B5")  '## Modify the input range as needed.
For Each aCell In rng.Cells
    Select Case Len(aCell)
        Case 12
            val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 9) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 8)
        Case 13
            val = "S-" & Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 10) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 4, Len(aCell) - 9)
        Case 15
            val = "SD-" & Mid(aCell, 5, Len(aCell) - 12) & "-" & Mid(aCell, 8, Len(aCell) - 12)
        Case 16
            val = "REF-" '## Modify as needed
        Case 17
            val = "REF-" '## Modify as needed
        Case Else
            'maybe warn the user this input is not anticipated...
            MsgBox "Unsupported length!", vbInformation
    End Select
    val = UCase(val)
    '## Append the values from column D,E:
    val = val & " " & aCell.Offset(, 2) & aCell.Offset(, 3)
    '## Write out to the workbook in column F, modify the "5" to specify a different location if needed e.g., "-1" would put it in column A, "0" would put in same column B, etc.
    aCell.Offset(, 4).Value = val
Next
End Sub
```